# Cómo crear una conexión TCP de móvil a PC en UWP

Tags: c#, socket, uwp, tcp

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación en UWP en la que desde mi móvil (es un Lumia con Windows 10 Mobile) actuando como cliente intenta conectarse con mi PC (con Windows 10) que actúa como servidor. Ambos están conectados a la misma red Wi-Fi, y es la que intento utilizar para que se comuniquen.

En la parte del cliente intento conectarme al PC con la siguiente linea:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect("192.168.0.17", 7);
```

donde la IP es la que le ha asignado mi router a mi PC.

En la parte del servidor tengo lo siguiente:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.17"), 7);
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(endPoint);
listener.Listen(10);
Socket client = listener.Accept();
text.Text = "Conectado !!";
```

El problema es que tanto el cliente como el servidor se quedan esperando indefinidamente. Está claro que el móvil y el PC no se están encontrando en 192.168.0.17:7, pero no se por qué.

Comment: Una prueba que puedes hacer es hacer un telnet a la IP y al puerto ( después de ejecutar el Server) si no hay conexión te dará un error de **connection closed**. Así puedes verificar si la parte del servidor funciona